# How do I make a HTML fallback via Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fallback, progressive-enhancement

What is the best way to make a HTML fallback via Angular?

I need something like this:

```
<span>{{angularText}} plain text</span>
```

The plain text would be a "backup" (perhaps generated by the server), in case the user doesn't have JavaScript enabled. Of course, if the user has JavaScript enabled, then I obviously don't want both to show.

Comment: To be honest, if you're using Angular, you're probably already making the assumption that the user has JS enabled.

Comment: Do you genuinely have a case of users that have no ability to run Javascript?

Comment: Go to a angular demo page, turn JS off and you'll see what happens. (hint: probably nothing, depending on the page. But you'll definitely see `{{foo}}`` all over the place.)

Comment: Actually you won't see anything like that: https://angularjs.org/
It has a HTML fallback.

Comment: It is not so much about the ability, but the will to use JavaScript, actually. JavaScript is the base for the majority of [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). With JavaScript enabled,  [browser tracking](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) becomes far more powerful, also when using anonymity systems like Tor, JavaScript can be used to find your actual IP address and [break your anonymity](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBJavaScriptEnabled). In my oppinion, it is a good idea to offer your concerned users at least read access without requiring JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. It seems to be a very valid question. +1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<span ng-bind="angularText">Default text from server</span>
```

?

But like the others have mentioned, why use Angular to create an app if there's a slight chance some of the intended users have JS disabled?

I suggest adding this to your site as well:

```
<noscript>
You do not have JS enabled.  Since this is an Angular based website, it won't do jack for you :-)
</noscript>
```

Comment: Well, of course it will not ... but the user will then see "Default text from server" and not the {{angularText}}.  Wasn't that the whole point of the question?  So the user will not see *both* the angular expression and the default static text?  Honestly I don't see why my answer was downvoted :-)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point. The page should not break just because the user has disabled (or doesn't even support!) JavaScript.

Comment: @user3634330 "Doesn't support JavaScript"? Come on, guy, check the year on your calendar!

Comment: @Blackhole, believe it or not, there are still users out there that prefer to turn JS support off.

Comment: I, for example, browse the web with JS completely blocked by default (frequent websites are whitelisted though...). If the site has something interesting, I will temporarily allow it to run JS. This prevents unwanted ads, pop-ups, slowing down of websites, and all manner of unwanted things. I'm sure I'm not the only one, especially since temporarily allowing JS if needed is just two mouse clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Inside index.html:

```
 <noscript>
         <h1>Your title</h1>
         <div style="somestyles...">
               Your content
           </div>
    </noscript>
```

If one wishes he/she can keep a skeleton of what the site supposed to have looked if js was enabled and then a request message inside  to enable
javascript .